# Преобразовать текст в биты

Tags: php, php7

Мне нужно преобразовать текст в биты, а потом эти биты заменить на единицу.
Использую вот такой скрипт для перевода текста в биты:

```
$inputStrBin = implode(file('file/change value.txt'));
echo $inputStrBin."</br>"; // вывод изначального текста

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($inputStrBin); $i++) {
    $strBin = decbin(ord($inputStrBin[$i])) . "\n";
    echo "Перевод текста в биты: </br>";
    echo $strBin."\n"; // вывод текста по битам
}
```

Информация берется из файла, выводиться изначальная информация из файла, а так же закодированное сообщение. Но теперь я хочу что бы сообщение было изменено на все "единицы".
И у меня получается вот такой код:

```
$inputStrBin = implode(file('file/change value.txt'));
echo $inputStrBin."</br>";

// Перевод текста в бит
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($inputStrBin); $i++) {
    $strBin = decbin(ord($inputStrBin[$i])) . "\n";
    echo "Перевод текста в биты: </br>";
    echo $strBin."\n";

    $arraySource = str_split($strBin);
    echo $arraySource; 
    $arraySource = str_split($strBin);
    $arrayBinary = array_map(function() {
        return 1;
    }, $arraySource);
    $outputStrBin = implode($arrayBinary);
    echo $outputStrBin;
}
```

Мне выводит мое число, но почему-то вместо изменения в единицу, пишет просто ARRAY. В чем проблема?

Comment: `$arraySource = str_split($strBin); echo $arraySource;` - массив выводится print'ом, var_dump'ом и прочими функциями, echo используется для вывода строк, отсюда у вас и берётся "ARRAY"

Comment: А как я могу вывести переменную вне цикла? А то оно получается склеивать все сразу

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перевод текста в биты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183629/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8b)