# Перевод текста в биты

Tags: php, php7

Нужно перевести текст в биты. Использую вот такой скрипт. Но не вне цикла переменная выводится не корректно. Подскажите что я не так делаю

```html
$inputStrBin = implode(file('file/change value.txt'));

$strBin = "";

// Перевод текста в бит
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($inputStrBin); $i++) {
    $strBin = decbin(ord($inputStrBin[$i])) . "\n";
    echo $strBin."\n";
}

echo "</br>".$strBin."</br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте тело цикла:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($inputStrBin); $i++) {
    $strBin .= decbin(ord($inputStrBin[$i])) . "\n";
}
```